# CMake error: The source directory does not exist

Tags: macos, git, cmake

I am using Mac Mountain Lion 10.8.4, git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)

When I run the command

```
 cmake "$ALICE_ROOT" \
```

in my build directory the following error is shown:

```
  CMake Error: The source directory "/opt/alice/aliroot/v5-05-77-AN/src" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem.
For me helped to create the `src` directory and symlink all sources in it.